# Rails validation with if

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having trouble getting my validation working properly. I am trying to check if the user has checked :noship then :weight must equal 0.

With the code below I get an "Undefined local variable noship" error

snippet from models/package.rb

```
class Package < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :campaign

  validates_presence_of :weight, :campaign

  validates :weight, numericality: { equal_to: 0 }, :if => :noship_test?


def noship_test?
  noship == true
end

  rails_admin do
    object_label_method do
      :custom_name
    end
  end
```

The :noship and :weight values are working and being saved correctly to my database

Comment: Am i getting it rigth: you have a noship column on the user table and you want to use it to validate package model? Are user and package associated with each other?

Comment: Yeah :noship has a column in my "campaigns" db, and :weight has a column in my "packages" db. package.rb  is associated with :campaign (edited my op to show more). 

I have an option for no shipping on my campaign form, but if that is checked I need to make sure that the user entered 0 into the weight field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `noship` belongs to campaign model, you'll need to do something like:

```
def noship_test?
  campaign && campaign.noship
end
```

However having such a method seems redundant, just pass a lambda to `if` key:

```
validates :weight, numericality: { equal_to: 0 }, :if => ->(r) { r.campaign && r.campaign.noship }
```

Comment: It doesn't work with Rails 5. Do you have any solution?